# Can the embedded MySQL DLL support multiple users processes accessing a DB?

Tags: mysql

I am currently comparing Firebird to MySQL Embedded for use in an application. I have found all the specs for [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/fb25_architecture_comparison.pdf) and I am looking for a similiar document regarding MySQL embedded.  If I can't find a document, below are the items I'm interested in for MySQL

- Can embedded MySQL server support multiple users (1-10 concurrent)?
- Does embedded MySQL server support multiple threads accessing the db?
- Can a MySQL DB location be on a remote share (CIFS, NFS, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following [presentation](https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/21/MySQL%20Embedded_%20Getting%20Started%20with%20libmysqld%20Presentation.ppt&chrome=true) that had the information I was looking for.

1. Embedded MySQL supports one process at a time accessing a file
2. Unsure about multiple threads, but since it all is running in one process, this may be OK
3. MySQL can use a file located anywhere that acts as a drive letter.

Also, databases use the same file format between the standard MySQL server and the Embedded Server which allows these to be easily integrated into a client/server installation.

Hope this information helps some else.